# Why does java.net.URL.toString throw a NullPointerException on EMR AMI 3.8.0?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, nullpointerexception, classpath, emr

My Hadoop job works fine on Amazon ElasticMapreduce AMI 3.7.0. But when I upgrade to AMI version 3.8.0, the toString method of the java.net.URL class starts throwing a NullPointerException:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at java.net.URL.toExternalForm(URL.java:925)
  at java.net.URL.toString(URL.java:911)
  at com.snowplowanalytics.iglu.client.repositories.HttpRepositoryRef.lookupSchema(HttpRepositoryRef.scala:602)
  at com.snowplowanalytics.iglu.client.Resolver.recurse$1(Resolver.scala:236)
  at com.snowplowanalytics.iglu.client.Resolver.lookupSchema(Resolver.scala:247)
  at com.snowplowanalytics.iglu.client.validation.ValidatableJsonMethods$$anonfun$verifySchemaAndValidate$2$$anonfun$apply$6$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(validatableJson.scala:171)
  at com.snowplowanalytics.iglu.client.validation.ValidatableJsonMethods$$anonfun$verifySchemaAndValidate$2$$anonfun$apply$6$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(validatableJson.scala:170)
  at scalaz.Validation$class.flatMap(Validation.scala:141)
  at scalaz.Success.flatMap(Validation.scala:347)
  at com.snowplowanalytics.iglu.client.validation.ValidatableJsonMethods$$anonfun$verifySchemaAndValidate$2$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(validatableJson.scala:170)
  at com.snowplowanalytics.iglu.client.validation.ValidatableJsonMethods$$anonfun$verifySchemaAndValidate$2$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(validatableJson.scala:169)
  at scalaz.Validation$class.flatMap(Validation.scala:141)
  at scalaz.Success.flatMap(Validation.scala:347)
  at com.snowplowanalytics.iglu.client.validation.ValidatableJsonMethods$$anonfun$verifySchemaAndValidate$2.apply(validatableJson.scala:169)
  at com.snowplowanalytics.iglu.client.validation.ValidatableJsonMethods$$anonfun$verifySchemaAndValidate$2.apply(validatableJson.scala:166)
  at scalaz.Validation$class.flatMap(Validation.scala:141)
  at scalaz.Success.flatMap(Validation.scala:347)
  at com.snowplowanalytics.iglu.client.validation.ValidatableJsonMethods$.verifySchemaAndValidate(validatableJson.scala:166)
  at com.snowplowanalytics.iglu.client.validation.ValidatableJsonNode.verifySchemaAndValidate(validatableJson.scala:244)
  at com.snowplowanalytics.snowplow.enrich.common.utils.shredder.Shredder$$anonfun$extractAndValidateJson$1$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(Shredder.scala:267)
  at com.snowplowanalytics.snowplow.enrich.common.utils.shredder.Shredder$$anonfun$extractAndValidateJson$1$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(Shredder.scala:266)
  at scalaz.Validation$class.flatMap(Validation.scala:141)
  at scalaz.Success.flatMap(Validation.scala:347)
  at com.snowplowanalytics.snowplow.enrich.common.utils.shredder.Shredder$$anonfun$extractAndValidateJson$1.apply(Shredder.scala:266)
  at com.snowplowanalytics.snowplow.enrich.common.utils.shredder.Shredder$$anonfun$extractAndValidateJson$1.apply(Shredder.scala:264)
  at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
  at com.snowplowanalytics.snowplow.enrich.common.utils.shredder.Shredder$.extractAndValidateJson(Shredder.scala:264)
  at com.snowplowanalytics.snowplow.enrich.common.utils.shredder.Shredder$.extractContexts$1(Shredder.scala:101)
  at com.snowplowanalytics.snowplow.enrich.common.utils.shredder.Shredder$.shred(Shredder.scala:108)
  at com.snowplowanalytics.snowplow.enrich.hadoop.ShredJob$$anonfun$loadAndShred$1.apply(ShredJob.scala:83)
  at com.snowplowanalytics.snowplow.enrich.hadoop.ShredJob$$anonfun$loadAndShred$1.apply(ShredJob.scala:80)
  at scalaz.Validation$class.flatMap(Validation.scala:141)
  at scalaz.Success.flatMap(Validation.scala:347)
  at com.snowplowanalytics.snowplow.enrich.hadoop.ShredJob$.loadAndShred(ShredJob.scala:80)
  at com.snowplowanalytics.snowplow.enrich.hadoop.ShredJob$$anonfun$5.apply(ShredJob.scala:170)
  at com.snowplowanalytics.snowplow.enrich.hadoop.ShredJob$$anonfun$5.apply(ShredJob.scala:169)
  at com.twitter.scalding.MapFunction.operate(Operations.scala:58)
  at cascading.flow.stream.FunctionEachStage.receive(FunctionEachStage.java:99)
  at cascading.flow.stream.FunctionEachStage.receive(FunctionEachStage.java:39)
  at cascading.flow.stream.SourceStage.map(SourceStage.java:102)
  at cascading.flow.stream.SourceStage.run(SourceStage.java:58)
  at cascading.flow.hadoop.FlowMapper.run(FlowMapper.java:130)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:452)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:344)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:171)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:166)
```

The URL on which the method is called is not null. The exception is thrown by the class's internal toExternalForm method.

Why does this happen?

This is the output of `java -version` on the cluster for AMI 3.8.0 (on both master and core nodes):

```
[hadoop@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx ~]$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_76"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_76-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.76-b04, mixed mode)
```

And for AMI 3.7.0 (on both master and core nodes):

```
[hadoop@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx ~]$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_71"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode)
```

Could the different JRE versions be to blame?

Comment: An example of a failing URL: `http://iglucentral.com/schemas/com.snowplowanalytics.snowplow/link_click/jsonschema/1-0-0`

Comment: What's the JRE version?

Comment: Okay, the failing line appears to be invoking a method on a transient field `handler`. Looks like serialization isn't properly restoring the state; since this is Hadoop, I presume that the URL in question has been shipped to a remote machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As reluctant as I am to make the claim, this appears to be a JVM bug. In the OpenJDK source for `java.net.URL`, the entirety of the `toExternalForm()` method is a delegation to a handler, which is a transient field:

```
public String toExternalForm() {
    return handler.toExternalForm(this);
}
```

The only way in which this could throw an NPE is if `handler` is null. As far as I can tell, all constructor paths and the `readObject(ObjectInputStream)` method ensure that the `handler` field is set and throw exceptions (either `MalformedURLException` or `IOException`) if it can't be. For example:

```
private synchronized void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream s)
     throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    s.defaultReadObject();  // read the fields
    if ((handler = getURLStreamHandler(protocol)) == null) {
        throw new IOException("unknown protocol: " + protocol);
    }
...
```

I note that there was a public JRE 7u79 release and would suggest trying that version if upgrading to Java 8 isn't feasible.